# Creating sequence number in crystal report based on parameter input (start number & end number) without connecting to database

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to create sequence number in crystal report based on parameter input (start number & end number) without refer to database?

Idea is i want to make a ticket with serial/sequence number. The start number and last number is input by the user.

This serial number is not refer to any field in database. Just serial number.

For input, i have winform with 2 textbox --> start number and end number.

Is it possible?

I tried to using running total, but looks like it should refer to database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Afaik CR always needs a datasource/dataset to generate lines. Do you have any database you can connect to? In this case you could use a "Command" as datasource and create and populate a temp table via script.

Comment: Hi mweber, yes i have database. but i don't need it to generate sequence / serial number. Goal is just print ticket number with sequence number without referring to any table.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant: CR can't render a report w/o querying a datasource - but you can write a Command script which does not query an existing table, but creates, populates and queries a temp table. (At least in most common DBMSs - which one do you have at hand?).

Comment: "Winform" in your question lets me assume that you're using CR embedded in a .NET application. In this case you could also bind a "Dataset" as source, like described in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crystal-report-in-windows-application-without-database-conn/

Comment: yes. i use CR embedded in a .NET app. and i use SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "Command" in Crystal Reports and create your desired resultset by creating and filling a table var within your TSQL script. See [1531012 - How to create a Command Object in Crystal Reports?](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1531012) for basic instructions regarding Commands. A TSQL script example creating a resultset with consecutive numbers:

```
DECLARE @begin INT = 500 /* to be bound to CR parameter */
DECLARE @end INT = 526 /* to be bound to CR parameter */
DECLARE @idx INT = 1 
DECLARE @numberstable TABLE (idx INT, number INT)
WHILE @begin < @end
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @numberstable (idx, number)
    VALUES (@idx, @begin)
    SET @idx = @idx + 1
    SET @begin = @begin + 1
END
SELECT * 
FROM @numberstable
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

Alternatively you can use a .NET Dataset as described in [this post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crystal-report-in-windows-application-without-database-conn/) and fill the dataset programmatically with your consecutive numbers.